# Rails full engine routes not loaded in Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails 3 application to Rails 4.  I use a full Rails engine as part of this application, where the engine routes are defined within the engine config/routes.rb on `Rails.application.routes.draw`

These routes were automatically loaded into my routes on Rails 3.2.x, but now the routes are not being loaded into my Rails 4 application.  Is there some type of additional configuration that is needed now to include these?

Comment: Is it packaged as a gem, which is loading a class extending ::Rails::Engine?

Comment: Yes; it's packaged as a gem and extends Rails::Engine

Comment: Your Gemfile has then `gem 'my_engine'` and the application.rb `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`?

Comment: Yes, it has both the gem specified and `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in the application.rb.

Comment: And the engine should not be calling `isolate_namespace` as it would be a mountable engine otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no additional config. Tried it out on a fresh engine. Do the same and then compare your setup.

```
 rails plugin new blorgh --full
```

Edit config/routes.rb on the engine, e.g

```
resources "blorghs"
```

Then on terminal

```
$ cd test/dummy
$ rake routes
```

Will show the blorgh routes

Another debugging advice:

If the engine is loaded correctly every class of it should be accessible from the rails console. Also stop spring if you're using it. It might have still caching the application without the engine loaded `bin/spring stop`

Comment: The Rails 4 documentation for full engines is completely missing; this must no longer be the preferred way to do things...  Spent a bunch of time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. In the end the problem was in the engine itself it was not handling requires properly for Rails versions above 3.

Comment: @bigtunacan, can you explain more what you mean by "not handling requires properly"?